# Is there a word for someone who is usually in the minority?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, expression-choice

My original question was *"Is there a legitimate word for '**a balancer**'?"* but I think it's a little hard to understand...

Let's just say there is a person, and most of the time, he is *in the minority*. It can be very simple, such as: he simply hates a song everybody likes (and vice versa), or he has a very long list of '*underrated movies*'. I guess he has a different (if not eccentric) taste comparing to most people..

On the other hand, he often does things that most people would refuse to do, too (whether he wants to or not). For example, most people wouldn't buy damaged goods, but he would. You can say he is sacrificing himself. To his mind, "If everybody wants perfection than who will care for the damaged?" or "There are certain people who would only accept the best, so there must be people who accept the worse, coexisting with the former."

This person does things that most people would never do, he stays in the minority so other people can be in the majority => some sort of "balancer"? You know, since he balances everything.. **So, is there a word for people like him?**

I know this is a long shot but please help me if you can, thank you!

Comment: The Russian words Menshevik (from minority) and Bolshevik (from majority) originally meant something similar - but they're not English and are never used in this way now :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do you call a person who does/thinks the opposite of the crowd for just that reason?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70526/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-does-thinks-the-opposite-of-the-crowd-for-just-tha) (Within which [**contrarian**](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/70527/2637) is the runaway top answer, but in many contexts **eclectic** would also be relevant.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers yeah I've just taken a look at it but mine's a little bit different... a contrarian may have no purpose of being contrary, but my 'balancer' is different because he felt that someone has to be.. so he considers the balancing job to be obligatory ' ^ '

Comment: If it "just so happens" that your subject often doesn't adopt the majority position (as opposed to *deliberately* doing so), most likely he is eclectic. Or perhaps you're interested in the concept of "devil's advocate" (who adopts the non-standard position in order to allow an issue to be debated). Or maybe you're thinking of the (esp. *British*) habit of *rooting for the underdog* - which we do in sporting events, etc., because we want to see an evenly-matched game that goes right to the wire in the tense final minutes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers wow, a *devil's advocate* could be the one, thank you! :) Though it's most likely to be used in debates/arguments, rather than my mentioned scenario, I don't think there's a better choice, so thanks again!

Comment: @Henley: Don't forget expressions like ["champion of the underdog"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22champion+of+the+underdog%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), if you want to cast your referent character in a more positive light.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I will, thank you :) and do you mind re-posting the devil's advocate as an Answer so that I can mark it Accepted?

Comment: @Henley: I don't think that would be "righteous", since I've already closevoted this question in favour of the earlier one. And although ***contrarian*** is the top answer there, I did actually post [***devil's advocate***](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/70566/2637) as a possible alternative myself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers in this question of mine specifically, _**devil's advocate**_ is closer to what I'm aiming at than _**contrarian**_. But fair enough :)

Comment: Can it be anti-populism? It is not only used in politics, it can be a philosophy also.

Comment: Also see  [What's the word for someone who always likes being different?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/127096)  and  [Is there a word to describe someone who tends to disagree with others only to upset them?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/79125),

Answer (score 15):

This person could be called a **[contrarian](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contrarian)**.

A *contrarian*, according to Merriam-Webster, is "a person who takes a contrary position or attitude". The term *non-conformist* could also apply. For someone in politics who opposes the majority, the word **[oppositionist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oppositionist)** is used. One adjective that could be used for consistently opposing a majority is *anti-establishment*.

Comment: Not at all.  Someone who is always in the **majority** can be just as much a contrarian.  And someone who is always in the minority need not always take a contrary position -- s?he need always take a contrary position only wrt the majority.

Comment: @Drew Au contraire, a contrarian always disagrees with the _established_ position. I should have used the OED definition: "A person who opposes or rejects _popular opinion_ [emphasis mine]". (It's slightly ironic that I am using an established source to define _contrarian_.)

Comment: I disagree. Shop around different dictionaries. A contrarian is someone who tends to **take an opposing position**. That's all. Someone can do that wrt any particular set of people (including wrt a majority on the issue in question, and including wrt each person and each position).

Comment: @Drew Touché...

Answer (score 6):

I would call such person a *maverick*.

> [maverick](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maverick): a person who refuses to follow the customs or rules of a group
>
> [maverick](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+maverick): an unorthodox or independent-minded person

Alternately, consider *oddball*.

> [oddball](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oddball): an eccentric or unconventional person

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly your definition of the "balancer", as you call him,  I think you may be referring to  what is usually called the **defender of lost causes**, meaning someone  who  for some reason is always on the part of people, things and situations which are the least accepted or preferred by the majority.

Answer (score 2):

The 'balancer' is engaged in what I would call a *quixotic* (or *Canute-like*) *enterprise.*

Answer (score 2):

An [**outlier**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/outlier?s=t), perhaps.

> **noun** someone who stands apart from others of his or her group, as by differing actions, beliefs, religious practices, etc.: an outlier among Muslims; an outlier among conservatives. Synonyms: outsider, nonconformist, maverick; original, eccentric, bohemian; dissident, dissenter, iconoclast, heretic.